# PHP constant __FILE__ not the same as that in the URL

Tags: php, linux, caching, rename, file-permissions

I am using PHP Version 5.4.20 on Centos 6.4.

In `var/www/html/oldDirecory/index.php`, I start off using `syslog(LOG_INFO,__FILE__);`.

Using PHP, I rename the directory using:

```
rename(dirname(__FILE__).'/oldDirectory', dirname(__FILE__).'/newDirectory');
```

My script then uses JS to redirect to the new URL using `window.location`. The next time the server is hit, `syslog(LOG_INFO,__FILE__);` still shows the old directory!

Using the Bash command line, I see the directory name has been changed.

I use `vi` to edit the file, change nothing, and then save it, and then `__FILE__` displays the correct directory.

I've tried making a simple script (without the JS redirect, several `includes()`, etc), but cannot seem to replicate the behavior.  I don't think this used to happen in early PHP versions, but it might be something else I added.  Maybe something to do with caching?  Sorry for the lack of information, but I am stumped!

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://derickrethans.nl/advent08.html) to find how `__FILE__` actually works

Comment: @MarkBaker.  Thank you Mark.  I have read the post several times, but am still confused.  Okay, __FILE__ gets evaluated at parser time.  I don't know how this causes my problems.  Please provide any other hints or advice.  Thank yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an opcode cache like APC?  If so, `touch` the affected file(s) after renaming the containing directory.  It's evaluated at parse time, but opcode caches store the results of the parse.

I successfully replicated your issue with APC.  Presumably, with the filename and inode numbers matching along with no modification time change makes it hit the cache.  Changing the modification time with [touch](https://www.php.net/touch) should do the trick.